# Python alternative to MATLAB's semilogy

Tags: python, matlab, plot, matlab-figure

What is the Python alternative for MATLAB's `semilogy` plotting function?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @anosha_rehan it is limited to a specific problem: namely the Python equivalent of MATLAB's `semilogy()`, which exists with almost 1-on-1 copyable syntax and usability within matplotlib. There's nothing too broad or vague about this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use matplotlib's [`semilogy()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.semilogy.html). matplotlib's functionality and syntax are generally similar to MATLAB's plotting routines and its documentation is rather extensive, including lots of examples.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.grid()

y = np.array([100,50,3,2,1.5,1.4,1.3,1.1,1])

plt.plot(y)
plt.title("Linear plot of y")

plt.figure()
plt.grid()
plt.semilogy(y)
plt.title("Semilog plot of y")
```

[image]
[image]